# Apache airflow cannot locate AWS credentials when using boto3 inside a DAG

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, airflow

We are migrating to Apache Airflow using ECS Fargate.

The problem we are facing, it's simple. We have a simple DAG that one of its tasks is to communicate with some external service in AWS (let's say, download a file from S3). This is the script of the DAG:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from datetime import datetime, timedelta


# default arguments for each task
default_args = {
    'owner': 'thomas',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}


dag = DAG('test_s3_download',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval=None) 

TEST_BUCKET = 'bucket-dev'
TEST_KEY = 'BlueMetric/dms.json'


# simple download task
def download_file(bucket, key):
    import boto3
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    print(s3.Object(bucket, key).get()['Body'].read())


download_from_s3 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='download_from_s3',
    python_callable=download_file,
    op_kwargs={'bucket': TEST_BUCKET, 'key': TEST_KEY},
    dag=dag)


sleep_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='sleep_for_1',
    bash_command='sleep 1',
    dag=dag)


download_from_s3.set_downstream(sleep_task)
```

As we have done other times when using docker, we create within the docker container, in `~/.aws` the `config` file that reads:

```
[default]
region = eu-west-1
```

and as long as the container is within the AWS boundaries, it'll resolve every request without any need to specify credentials.

This is the `Dockerfile` we are using:

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.7

USER root

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/entrypoint.sh"]

RUN mkdir -p /home/airflow/.aws \
&& touch /home/airflow/.aws/config \
&& echo '[default]' > /home/airflow/.aws/config \
&& echo 'region = eu-west-1' >> /home/airflow/.aws/config

RUN ["chown", "-R", "airflow", "/home/airflow"]

USER airflow

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

# # Expose webUI and flower respectively
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 5555
```

and everything works like a charm. Directory and change of owner are done successfully but when running the DAG, it fails saying:

```
...
...
File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 160, in sign
    auth.add_auth(request)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
[2020-08-24 11:15:02,125] {{taskinstance.py:1117}} INFO - All retries failed; marking task as FAILED
```

So we are thinking that the worker node of Airflow does use another user.

Does any of you know what's going on? Thank you for any advice/light you can provide.

Comment: what user airflow runs as  ? Make sure the user have access to the credentials. Run the boto3 commands becoming that user inside docker container(where airflow is running). Also other better option would be to use airflow connection approach with S3<>operators. Take a look at this https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/s3_list_operator.html

Comment: also see if you can specify boto3 your custom .aws/config path. Maybe its trying the default location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a proper `task_role_arn` for the task definition. This role is the one assumed by the processes triggered inside the container. Another annotation is that the error should not read:

`Unable to locate credentials`

that misleads, but

`Access Denied: you don't have permission to s3:GetObject`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now. How did you figure out that the error raised was incorrectly described?

Comment: I searched for information and saw that there was another role (task_role_arn) that I was not defining at all. I added it and it worked without needing to change the Docker image at all (I was quite sure that the docker image was correct and the credentials were defined as expected, I had done that quite a few times).